# Why were there no interrogation scenes with Jack and Henley?

Tags: now-you-see-me

In [*Now You See Me*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1670345/), during the FBI investigation of the supposed bank robbery (the first trick of the Four Horsemen), they're all interrogated separately by Agent Rhodes in the usual plain grey interrogation rooms. But after they play their tricks on him, they end up getting released due to missing evidence.

**But why were only the interrogations of Daniel and Merritt shown, and not those of Jack and Henley too?** Were those scenes not in the script in the first place, or were they just cut from the movie later on? And why were they not shown? Was it just because they wouldn't have been as entertaining as the other two interrogations, or is there more to it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whether there were any interrogation scenes with Jack and Henley in the first draft(s) of the script, or if they actually made it as far as production, I can't answer. But, I can tell you why they didn't make the final cut. Unlike Daniel and Merritt, Jack and Henley simply didn't have anything to contribute that would either drive the plot forward or set something up.

The interrogation scenes with Merritt did two things. They revealed how talented he was (and obviously still is) which made, among other things, their second trick more believable (where it was his mentalist knowledge that gave them Arthur's security information). He also set up the romantic sub-plot (which wasn't fully explored in the movie, but it was still there) which was later paid off at the end when Rhodes met Alma at the bridge.

The scenes with Daniel were the ones that drove the plot forward. He was the one who swapped Rhodes' phone and also the one who explained why they got to walk after having committed the bank robbery.

> **Rhodes:** You are literally begging to be arrested, you know that?
>
> **Daniel:** If it means you would actually do it, then yeah. But you won't... Because if you did, it means that you and the FBI and your friends at Interpol actually believe—at an institutional level—in magic. The press would have a field day... And we'd be even more famous than we already are, and you guys would look like idiots even more than you already are. [...] Listen, you have what we in the business like to call "nothing up your sleeve..." And you know it.

Answer (score 4):

Each person among the four horsemen had an area of expertise. Daniel and Merritt had their area of expertise in manipulation and psychology (mentalism) while those of jack and henley were stealing and (I guess) getting out of tight spot.

Now clearly Daniel and Merritt's area of expertise was strong enough to seem to be useful and intimidating. Also these two were probably more senior than the other two so the FBI probably thought it to be useless to interview them. At this point in the movie I guess the point was to prove that these guys were one step ahead of the FBI. This point wouldn't be put forward in an intimidating manner by the other two. As you might know if you watched the full movie Agent Rhodes might have easily been playing himself in their hands and that probably was the case here.

Comment: er, the FBI wouldn't find two *suspects* to be useless to interrogate. They would have interrogated 100 of them if there were that many present. If they were in an interrogation room, then they were interrogated. It just wasn't shown.

Answer (score 4):

When the FBI brought in the Horsemen for interrogation, they led them to separate rooms to be interrogated separately. Consider that the interrogation was totally planned, and was an opportunity for the Horsemen to steal Rhodes' phone. And to intimidate the FBI into following false trails. McKinney was the mentalist, he tried to goad Rhodes into getting frustrated. He played mentalist tricks to lead them off track. Daniel was the real plot - he had to get Rhodes' phone. Apart from these two, the others probably gave nothing to the plot. They simply were interrogated, and let go. They did not have any *roles* to play during the interrogation.